# Rename file names with accents in shell

Tags: regex, linux, wordpress, bash, shell

I have had an error while migrating my files from another server.

Now, all wordpress files are like this:

TendÃƒÂªncia-Moda-Feminina-2014

I need to have this name: Tendência-Moda-Feminina-2014

I would like to know if someone has a regex to replace those "codes" to the normal portuguese accents.

There are others codes that I need to exchange to my accented letters.

My foldes are like this:

2014
  - 01
  - 02
  ...
  - 12

2015
  - 01
  - 02
  ...
  - 12

Its the uploads foldes of wordpress structure.

Comment: This can't be fixed by a regex. This was caused because one of the servers can not read utf8. You should make sure both your servers are configured correctly and transfer again

Comment: The old server already has this bug. So the unique way to fix it is renaming the files...